# code completion with PHPStorm for Dojo (specifically for dojo.require)

Tags: ide, dojo, javascript, code-completion, phpstorm

I use PHPStorm 3.0.3 and would like to ask my question regarding code completion specifically regarding the `require`-method in Dojo 1.6.

The example code would be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require([...]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now after reaching the second letter in `require`, PHPStorms suggests me a lot of methods and attributes, but not `require`.

[image]

**How do I make PHPStorm show me `require`?** (code inspection? configure dojo as a library?)

This issue I face with many Dojo-methods and attributes which I use frequently. `require` is more a generic choice.

*If this is not possible, I also accept that as an answer, as long as a technical reason is given.*

Answer (score 1):

i have never used PHPStorm, but i know that with with Eclipse or Aptana or you need to do is download the dojo.doc.sdocml and every thing will appear on your code assist and aptana studio is free just my thought.

Comment: +1 b/c for some reason it triggered the right keywords for a google search

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Dojo
2. File/Settings/Directories
3. Add the Dojo-folder via "Add Content Root"
4. Mark it as "Resource Root"
5. Ok / wait until indexing is done

that's it

Answer (score 0):

File -> Settings -> Javascript -> Libraries -> Download

Select dojo, click "download and install", make sure the "enabled" checkbox is set.

Problem is, you currently get a whole bunch of unrelated methods suggested from all over dojo. So it's kind of useless atm.